# Data transfer between Ubuntu and CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ethernet, file-transfer

How do I transfer data between Ubuntu and CentOS  using LAN cable, in the same network? I tried installing Samba which did not go well in CentOS.

Comment: have you tried `ssh`?

Comment: @Tejas: I think you meant `sftp` or `scp`.

Comment: Indeed `scp`....@Ouki

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to set up SSH and use SCP. If you are transferring files to the CentOS server, do the following:

On CentOS:

```
sudo yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients
sudo chkconfig sshd on
sudo service sshd start
```

From the Ubuntu box, run:

```
scp sourcefile.txt username@ip.of.centos:/target/directory/
```

Comment: Ubuntu desktop says `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
lost connection
`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SSH server installed on both of them, you can use [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) or better make use of [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Comment: `rsync` requires that a `rsync` server is installed on one of the servers.

Comment: `rsync` requires indeed that it is installed on both hosts. However `rsync` can make use the SSH connection for the transfer.

Comment: `rsync` does not require using rsync server. Only the normal `rsync` client is enough. `rsync -e ssh source username@destination:path` is the syntax for RSync over SSH.

Comment: @Spack & Tero Kilkanen: thanks. I always used rsyncd by the past

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell on the destination host and type:

```
~# nc -v -v -l -n -p 2222 > file.out
```

Now open a shell on you sender host and type the following commands:

```
~# pv -t -r -a -b /dev/zero | nc -v -v -n DESTINATION_IP_HERE 2222 < file.in
```

Comment: While this might work - I think it's doing it the hard way.